# How to use or operator in python

Tags: python

In my project I have used or but in some cases it works and in some cases it fails me..
I cant understand Why?

```
if (a or b) is not True:
    # This works for me


if (a or b) == "Django" and (c or d) == "Pyramid":
    # This fails me everytime
```

Comment: You should read the docs - you have no idea what "or" really does ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`a or b` evaluates to `a` if `a` evaluates to `True`. If `a` evaluates to `False`, `a or b` evaluates to `b`.

For instance:

```
[] or 'a' #evaluates to 'a'
'a' or None #evaluates to 'a'
[] or None #evaluates to None
None or [] #evaluates to []
```

Your `(a or b) == 'Django'` should be `a == 'Django' or b == 'Django'`.

```
('Django' or 'Nomatterwhat') == 'Django' #True
([] or 'Django') == 'Django' #True
('Mono' or 'Django') == 'Django' #False
```

---

Having said the theoretical part, try running this little program, to see how `or` and `and` work (especially the lazy evaluation part):

```
def x():
    print('X')
    return False

def y():
    print('Y')
    return True

print ('-' * 20)
x() or y()
print ('-' * 20)
y() or x()
print ('-' * 20)
x() and y()
print ('-' * 20)
y() and x()
```

Comment: No second question from the answer you gave me...Thank you

Comment: Minor issue, but in python `yield` has a specific meaning w.r.t. generators and iterators, so technically `[] or 'a'` does not `yield` anything.

Comment: @aquavitae Please see my question to your answer. I am really intrigued.

Answer (score 1):

if a == 'Django' or b == 'Django':

Answer (score 0):

Your parentheses are in the wrong place.  `(a or b)` will always return the first of `a` or `b` which evaluates to True, so:

```
>>> a = "Django"
>>> b = "Pyramid"
>>> (a or b)
"Django"
>>> (a or b) == "Django"
True
```

but

```
>>> (b or a)
"Pyramid"
>>> (b or a) == "Django"
False
```

What you actually want to write is:

```
>>> a == "Django" or b == "Django"
True
```

However, an alternative way of writing it which may be better in many cases is:

```
if "Django" in (a, b) or "Pyramid" in (a, b):
    ...
```

Or, if there are many options:

```
if set([a, b, c, ...]) & set(["Django", "Pyramid", ...]):
    ...
```

Comment: In which version of python and in which implementation resolves `'Django' or 'Pyramid'` to `True`? And even more interesting: Why should `('Django' or 'Pyramid') == 'Django'` be `False`?

Comment: I tried it in both 3.3 and 2.7 (cython) and in both versions I get completely different results as the ones you posted.

Comment: Sorry - typo!  It should be "Django", I'll correct the answer and make the meaning clearer

Comment: Y if "Django" in (a, b) or "Pyramid" in (a, b): works... Is it a good practise to use this??

Comment: @manjusha Nothing wrong about it. Also see the documentation for `all` and `any`.